# How to add multiple number of models in one cart (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm using **PostgresSQL** as *DB*, **Django** as *backend* and **HTML, CSS, Javascript** as *Frontend*. I have Multiple number of product `Models` and I want to add all those models in one cart. So, I had Successfully add *One* of the model in cart. But

> I want to add different products like Refrigerator, Fans, Washing
> Machine, ... etc. in one cart

So, how it will work?

*The Codes goes here:*

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    joined_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name


class Regrigeratior(models.Model):
    image_src = models.URLField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="processor name")
    brand = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
    ....

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Fans(models.Model):
    image_src = models.URLField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="processor name")
    brand = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
    ....

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
.
.
.

class Cart(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cart: " + str(self.id)

#                                      
class CartProduct(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    refrigerator = models.ForeignKey(Refrigerator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    subtotal = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cart: " + str(self.cart.id) + " CartProduct: " + str(self.id)
```

> **I have succesfully add Refrigerator Model in the cart**

**views.py**

```
class AddToCartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "status.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        refrigerator_id = self.kwargs['ref_id']
        refrigerator_obj = Refrigerator.objects.get(id = refrigerator_id)
        cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        if cart_id:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id = cart_id)
            this_product_in_cart = cart_obj.cartproduct_set.filter(refrigerator = refrigerator_obj)
        
            if this_product_in_cart.exists():
                cartproduct = this_product_in_cart.last()
                cartproduct.quantity += 1
                cartproduct.subtotal += refrigerator_obj.price
                cartproduct.save()
                cart_obj.total += refrigerator_obj.price
                cart_obj.save()
            else:
                cartproduct = CartProduct.objects.create(
                    cart = cart_obj, refrigerator = refrigerator_obj, rate = refrigerator_obj.price, quantity = 1, subtotal = refrigerator_obj.price)
                cart_obj.total += processor_obj.price
                cart_obj.save() 
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.create(total=0)
            self.request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
            cartproduct = CartProduct.objects.create(
                cart = cart_obj, refrigerator = refrigerator_obj, rate = refrigerator_obj.price, quantity = 1, subtotal = refrigerator_obj.price)
            cart_obj.total += refrigerator_obj.price
            cart_obj.save()

        return context
```

**So, Now I have Fan as a Model (and many more models). So how it will get add to the same cart?**

Comment: hi, are you building an e-commerce site?

Comment: Yes, I am Building an e-commerce website

Comment: ok then you are written logic is not efficient and not good.

Comment: Then how it will work for multiple models?

Comment: You'd need to use generic relationships so that django will utilise the content type ID and the object ID to link to any type of object. Docs are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: You should also consider using an existing e-commerce system. There are well established apps for django that already exist, and given the complexity of this type of application, you'd save yourself a lot of time by using something available with pip.

Comment: ok @markwalker_I will try and let you know that is it helpful for me. Thank you for suggestion

Comment: Hello @markwalker_ As you said about **generic relaitionship** is looking interesting and one thing, Can you refer some of the established apps which are already exist. So I can complete this work as soon as possible. Thank you in advance sir.

Comment: @santoshChauhan Take a look through here; https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/ecommerce/

Comment: Hello @KiranChauhan, can you help me with this. is it I'm going on right track or not. Please let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759735/how-to-show-child-table-in-django-rest-framework-api-view

Comment: hello @markwalker_ can you help me with this. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67783551/get-all-items-with-all-properties-using-django-multi-table-inheritance-and-djang)

Answer (score 1):

## I have designed a basic model here

```
   class Customer(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        joined_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.full_name
    
    
    class ProductCategory(models.Model):
        """
        storing product category to link with every product
        a category like Fan, Refrigerator...etc
        """
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="product category")
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    class Product(models.Model):
        image_src = models.URLField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="processor name")
        category = model.ForeignKey(ProducyCategory,null=True,blank=True,on_delet=model.SET_NULL
        brand = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
        ....
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
   
    
    class CartItem(models.Model):
        """
         Cart contain User and  Product
        """
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True,blank=True,on_delet=model.SET_NULL)
        total = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    
        def __str__(self):
            return "Cart: " + str(self.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a new model for products with fields image_src, name and brand. Making different models for different Categories is not effective.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used Multi Table inheritance for that